# What's the alternative to TAILQ_HEAD in Delphi?

Tags: c, delphi, code-conversion

The code I'm trying to convert from C is this:

```
struct DebugEventQueueElement {
  TAILQ_ENTRY(DebugEventQueueElement) entries;
  DebugEvent de;
};

#pragma pack()

TAILQ_HEAD(debugEventQueueHead, DebugEventQueueElement);
```

So far I've understood that `TAILQ_ENTRY` alternative is `TQueue` from Contnrs. What should `TAILQ_HEAD` be replaced with tho? Preferably with an example.

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/tailq.3.html)?

Comment: And note that tailqs provide a lot of operations that TQueue doesn't. You might need a different data structure depending on what the C code does with it.

Comment: @Shawn I indeed have read the docs but they didn't help me in the part of understanding the part of "how to implement" because Delphi doesn't have macros as far as i know.